# Rails 5: Uninitialized constant in view/controller but not console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In my Rails 5 app I have a module in app/lib

```
module LibClass
  CONSTANT_NAME = ‘somevalue’
end
```

Then in a model I reference the module:

```
class SomeModel < ApplicationRecord
  def lib_class_constant
    LibClass::CONSTANT_NAME
  end
end
```

Everything works as expected when I call lib_class_constant on an instance of a SomeModel in console

But if I do the same in a view:

```
<%= some_model_instance.lib_class_constant %>
```

I get an error along the lines of:

> uninitialized constant SomeModel::LibClass

If I reference the module directly in the view:

```
<%= LibClass::CONSTANT_NAME %>
```

I get an error along the lines of:

> uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::LibClass

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try `::LibClass::CONSTANT_NAME`

Comment: @Vasilisa thanks, but that didn't work. It un-nests it, but I still get `uninitialized constant LibClass`. This is only in view / controller works fine outside of those contexts

Comment: Try to stop rails server and run `spring stop && rails server`

Comment: Make sure LibClass is defined in lib_class.rb or the autoloading Gods will be angry.

Comment: Did you require the file (require 'lib_class')?

Comment: @glyoko that was it [facepalm]. Interesting how it still worked everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the line `include LibClass` right after `class SomeModel < ApplicationRecord`  ? 
Otherwise have you checked that models and files have the right names? i.e. sometimes you rename a model without renaming the file accordingly or vice versa...

Comment: It was the file name. I was used to lib files not being name sensitive, but it was in app/lib and not /lib so the autoloading wasn't working in some contexts.